# Java - How to set timeout for Event Dispatch thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, dialog, timeout

I have a Java application were some operations take some time to load, so instead of freezing the program while the operation completes i show a "Please wait..." dialog using this code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        pleaseWaitDialog.setVisible( true );
    }
});
```

Sometimes the operation being executed hangs for some reason, so i would like to set a timeout period for this "please wait..." dialog to automatically disappear after 5 minutes and show an error message. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept would be to use a single run Swing `Timer`, that when triggered would allow you to dispose of the dialog, for example...

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TimeoutDialog dialog = new TimeoutDialog(5 * 60, (Window) null, "Testing");
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.add(new TestPane());
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel("This is a bad idea"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Don't tell me"), gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

    public class TimeoutDialog extends JDialog {

        private long timeOut = 90 * 1000;
        private long startTime;
        private Timer timer;
        private String originalTitle;

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut) {
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Frame owner) {
            super(owner);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Frame owner, boolean modal) {
            super(owner, modal);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Frame owner, String title) {
            super(owner, title);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Frame owner, String title, boolean modal) {
            super(owner, title, modal);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Frame owner, String title, boolean modal, GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
            super(owner, title, modal, gc);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Dialog owner) {
            super(owner);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Dialog owner, boolean modal) {
            super(owner, modal);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Dialog owner, String title) {
            super(owner, title);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Dialog owner, String title, boolean modal) {
            super(owner, title, modal);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Dialog owner, String title, boolean modal, GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
            super(owner, title, modal, gc);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Window owner) {
            super(owner);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Window owner, ModalityType modalityType) {
            super(owner, modalityType);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Window owner, String title) {
            super(owner, title);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Window owner, String title, ModalityType modalityType) {
            super(owner, title, modalityType);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        public TimeoutDialog(long timeOut, Window owner, String title, ModalityType modalityType, GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
            super(owner, title, modalityType, gc);
            init(timeOut);
        }

        protected void init(double timeOutValue) {

            this.timeOut = Math.round(timeOutValue * 1000);

            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    long runningTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    System.out.println(runningTime + "/" + timeOut);
                    if (runningTime >= timeOut) {
                        timer.stop();
                        dispose();
                    } else {
                        String title = originalTitle + " [" + (((timeOut - runningTime) / 1000) + 1) + "]";
                        setTitle(title);
                    }
                }
            });

            originalTitle = getTitle();
            String title = originalTitle + " [" + ((timeOut / 1000)) + "]";
            setTitle(title);
            addPropertyChangeListener("title", new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                        originalTitle = (String) evt.getNewValue();
                    }
                }
            });

            addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                    timer.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                    timer.stop();
                }

            });
        }

    }

}
```

Another idea might be to use some kind of observer pattern whose intention is to send regular "heart beats" to all interested parties.

Your long running process would periodically send out a "heart beat"/"pulse" (at relatively regular intervals) while it was still working.  If for some reason, it stopped working, the interested parties would know because they'd not received a pulse within in prescribed timeout period and could take appropriate action - just as an idea